# Replacing multiple letters in a word with number in python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Cant seem to figure out how to replace letters with numbers. for e.g.

lets say

```
     'a' , 'b' and 'c' should be replaced by "2".
     'd' , 'e' and 'n' should be replaced by "5".
     'g' , 'h' and 'i' should be replaced by "7".
```

The string I want to replace is `again`. The output i want to get is `27275`.
The outcome of these numbers should be in strings.

so far i have got:

```
def lett_to_num(word):
    text = str(word)
    abc = "a" or "b" or "c"
    aef = "d" or "e" or "n"
    ghi = "g" or "h" or "i"
    if abc in text:
        print "2"
    elif aef in text:
        print "5"
    elif ghi in text:
        print "7"
```

^I know the above is wrong^

What function should I write?

Comment: What function do you think you should write? Show a modicum of effort and then we'll be more likely to help you

Comment: it was just an example. so i could spell the word 'again'.

Comment: FYI, `aef = "d" or "e" or "n"` is really just `aef = "d"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use maketrans from string:

```
from string import maketrans
instr = "abcdenghi"
outstr = "222555777"
trans = maketrans(instr, outstr)
text = "again"
print text.translate(trans)
```

Output:

```
 27275
```

maketrans from string module gives byte mapping from instr to outstr. When we use translate, if any character from instr is found, it would be replaced with corresponding character from outstr.

Comment: Maybe mention that in python3.x this is a string method, `str.maketrans`.

Comment: No, in python 2.7 you will have to `from string import maketrans` where as in python 3.x, any string has the `maketrans` method: `"a string".maketrans()`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Since it seems you're trying to learn, I'll avoid advanced uses of the libraries. One way would be the following:

```
def lett_to_num(word):
    replacements = [('a','2'),('b','2'),('d','5'),('e','5'),('n','5'),('g','7'),('h','7'),('i','7')]
    for (a,b) in replacements:
       word = word.replace(a,b)
    return word

print lett_to_num('again')
```

Another way which is close to what you were trying to do in the code you showed in your question:

```
def lett_to_num(word):
    out = ''
    for ch in word:
        if ch=='a' or ch=='b' or ch=='d':
            out = out + '2'
        elif ch=='d' or ch=='e' or ch=='n':
            out = out + '5'
        elif ch=='g' or ch=='h' or ch=='i':
            out = out + '7'
        else:
            out = out + ch
    return out
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> d = {'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 
         'e': 5, 'd': 5, 'g': 7, 
         'i': 7, 'h': 7, 'n': 5}

>>> ''.join(map(str, [d[x] if x in d.keys() else x for x in 'again']))
'27275'
>>>
>>> ''.join(map(str, [d[x] if x in d.keys() else x for x in 'againpp']))
'27275pp'
>>>
```